plt.Tricontour plotting lines exceeding provided data
I have code in which I am trying to plot 3d data using lines. The data that I am providing is only till the black line, yet tricountour if plotting weird lines that exceed the black line and are beyond the data.
The data I am using is X, Y, Z
This is the link to the data:
X, Y, Z Data
`
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Book1.csv")

X = np.array((df["X"])) 

Y = np.array((df["Y"])) 

Z = np.array((df["Z"])) 

countour = plt.tricontour(X/340, Y, Z, levels=[100, 200, 500, 1000])
plt.axis([0, 0.6, 0, 40.1])
plt.show()

`

Can you please advice on how to get rid of the lines exceeding the black line?
The expected output should be like the following plot:


Your question is hard to answer without reproducible data. tricontour creates a convex triangle mesh from the x and y coordinates, and then draws lines connecting the interpolated z values on their edges. As such, it can't easily reproduce a non-convex area.

The data is quite extensive, I don't know how to upload such large amounts of data.

This is the link to the data:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19CGMX3qDBCbGU2D2uL0ehPGTrOmxtLHP/view?usp=drive_link

"This is the link to the data" → ACCESS DENIED

Access updated.
